# Viewing (and managing) software compiled from "foreign" sources

Tags: package-management, compiling, software-sources

I want to see all of the software I've compiled from extra-repository sources, sources that aren't on my etc/apt/sources.list or in ppas. To clarify I'm not including .deb files- just archives. The purpose is for security and management, particularly updates. Thanks!

Comment: Start by keeping track of "all of the software I've compiled from extra-repository sources".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment above. To find all files on your system that were NOT installed through the `dpkg` packaging system, read `man dpkg-query`, `man find` (to reduce the files checked - I'm checking everything:

```
sudo find / -type f -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -n 1 dpkg -S | \
    grep "no path found matching pattern" >>/tmp/not-owned-by-dpkg
```

Since this will, for each file on the system, search every package for the filename, it's going to take a loooong time.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't it be faster if I looked for relevant formats like .tar, .zip, etc? How would I pipe that in?

Comment: The existence (or not) of any archive file(`.tar`,`.tgz`,`.zip`, ...) has NO relationship to what software is installed.